# How to fix an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception: -1 in ArrayDeque

Tags: java, arraydeque

I am getting an error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

and it refers to method inject:

```
deque[back] = x;
```

I also have methods for push and pop which add and remove items at the front but those work fine.

The idea is to use an array-based implementation as deque, where inject and eject insert item at the back and remove item at the back.

```
  public void inject(int x){

        if (elementCount == size){

            System.out.println("The Deque is Full");
        } else {



            deque[back] = x;            
            back = (back - 1) % size;            
            elementCount ++;

        }

    }

    public class Deque {

    int[] deque;
    int front;
    int back;
    int size;
    int elementCount;

  public Deque(int s){

           size = s;
           deque = new int[size];

           front = 1;
           back = 0;        
           elementCount = 0; //n of elements

     }

    public int getRear(){

        return deque[back];
    }   

    public int getFront(){

        return deque[front];

    }


 public void inject(int x){

            if (elementCount == size){

                System.out.println("The Deque is Full");
            } else {

                deque[back] = x;            
                back = (back - 1) % size;            
                elementCount ++;

     }

  }

   public void eject(){

            if (elementCount == 0){

                System.out.println("The deque is empty");

            }else{

                back = (back + 1) % size;
                elementCount--;
        }

    }

 }
```

Comment: Why do you have a class named `Deque` when there is already a [`Deque` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) and an [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) concrete type?

Comment: I am asked to create it myself with pop, push, inject and eject methods

Comment: `back = (back - 1) % size;` is `(0 - 1) % size` and that is `-1` (assuming size is any positive value, such as one).

Answer (score 0):

You have in multiple places:

```java
back = (back - 1) % size;
```

That doesn't work like you think it does when `back` is originally `0`, where it becomes `-1 % size`, which is usually `-1`. In the places where it appears, you should instead use:

```java
back = (size + back - 1) % size;
```

Answer (score -1):

First thing I notice is you are using too many variables for this problem.  If you break it down you only need 3 variables.  the array, the size of the array and current location in the array for inject and eject.  This is a LiFo( Last in First Out) order.

```
public void inject(int x){

    if (this.deque.size() == this.size){ //check for full array

        System.out.println("The Deque is Full");
    } else {



        this.deque[this.back+1] = x;  //input new item next slot            
        this.back ++; //increment back to new input where eject would pull from           
        }

}

public class Deque {

int[] deque;
int back;
int size;

public Deque(int s){

       this.size = s;
       this.deque = new int[size];

       this.back = 0;        
 }
```

this should also solve your array index issue I am not sure why you were using a Modulo function '%' for the current location of back.

Comment: Deques have two ends. They aren't stacks. Presumably, they're using `%` to implement a circular buffer.

Comment: The idea is to use an array-based implementation as deque, where inject and eject insert item at the back and remove item at the back.         This was the problem he was asking to solve, not an actual linked list implmentation

Comment: A circular buffer is generally implemented using an array.

Comment: Only problem I see there is he hasn't even implemented a method to see if there is existing data in that point in the array so if you implement the code above fix the index error he would eventually be overwriting data that was input into the deque.